# Python download files from FTP ignoring the missing ones

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've a list of numbers on csv file like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

And an ftp server with files named like those numbers:

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
4.jpg
5.jpg
```

( 3.jpg is missing )

I want to download all the files of the FTP if the filename is on that csv list.

On my code i can successfully download the files but when it tryes to download a missing file on FTP the program crashes with:

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error ftp error: [Errno ftp error] 550 Can't change directory to 3.jpg: No such file or directory>
```

Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2, shutil
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from ftplib import FTP
FTP_server = 'ftp://user:pass@server.com/'
ftp = FTP_server+'the/path/to/files/'
class Test:
    def Get(self):
        data = pd.read_csv('test.csv',encoding='utf-8',delimiter=';')
        #data['REF'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
        #data.dropna(subset=['REF'], inplace=True)
        data['REF'] = data['REF'].astype(int)
        new_data = data['REF']
        for ref in new_data:
            file = str(ref)+str('.jpg')
            ftpfile = urllib2.urlopen(ftp+file)
            localfile = open(file, 'wb')
            shutil.copyfileobj(ftpfile, localfile)

Try = Test()
Try.Get()
```

I'm trying to make an if inside the for loop but i can't get it working, someone can give me some idea or tip plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get acquainted with [try-except blocks](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions) to handle this:

```
for ref in new_data:
    try:    
        file = str(ref)+str('.jpg')
        ftpfile = urllib2.urlopen(ftp+file)
        localfile = open(file, 'wb')
        shutil.copyfileobj(ftpfile, localfile)
    except urllib2.URLError: print("-I- Skipping",file," - doesn't exist.")
```

Comment: Thanks !! Worked perfectly, i'll read the exception handling docs, thanks for the info